# iPhone web app - How to uploade local photos in browser?

Tags: iphone, webkit, jqtouch

Everyone, I have really tried, but I can't find out how to upload photos from my iPhone to a server with the iPhone browser. I have tried with simple HTML like this:

```
<input type="file" name="foto" />
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

I use the jQuery and jQTouch libraries if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in a web app. Use UIImagePicker inside a native iPhone app